# Ask turtle "without" [blah?]

Tags: netlogo, agent-based-modeling

I have defined a `blah?` as a property of a turtle under `turtles-own`.

now in the `to go` i want turtles with blah? property to do something and I want turtles without blah? property to do something slightly different.

For example:

```
ask turtles with [blah?]
[forward 2]

ask turtles with [not blah?] ; this won't work but i am trying to figure out how to do this

[forward 1]
```

so `ask turtles with [not blah?]` won't work; how  can I do that>

Comment: ask turtles with [not blah?] should indeed work.  How do you know it is not working?  I assume blah? has been defined as either true or false for all turtles?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! It is preferred, when possible as in this case, to provide a [mre]: this means providing the shortes-possible piece of code that is necessary to reproduce (by just copying it, pasting it and running it) the type of problem you are experiencing. This will help others see what is happening without the need to guess what could have been done wrong. The answer I posted contains such an example (without the problem, of course). Also, in the future please include details of the error messages you receive as these too are helpful for debugging.

Answer (score 2):

For what I can guess, the problem must be of the sort that you define `blah?` as `TRUE` for the turtles whose `blah?` is true, but you do not define it as `FALSE` for the turtles whose `blah?` is false. This would result in some turtles having `blah? = TRUE`, and some others having `blah? = 0` (because 0 is the default value in NetLogo for all custom variables).

This would cause `not` to give an error, because `not` expects a boolean value but it finds a `0` instead.

The solution is to define `blah?` for all turtles, and not only for those who should have it as true:

```
turtles-own [
  blah?
]


to setup
  clear-all
  
  create-turtles world-height [
    setxy (min-pxcor) (who + min-pycor)
    set heading 90

    ifelse (random 2 < 1)
      [set blah? TRUE
       set color yellow]
      [set blah? FALSE
       set color cyan]
  ]
end


to go
  ask turtles with [blah?] [
    forward 2
  ]
  
  ask turtles with [not blah?] [
    forward 1
  ]
end
```

---

A suggestion: it would probably be better to use one `ask` command-block coupled with `ifelse` (overall: *n* turtles being asked, *n* conditions being evaluated), rather than two `ask` command-blocks both using `with` (overall: *n* turtles being asked but *2n* conditions being evaluated).

The `go` procedure would look like:

```
to go
  ask turtles [
    ifelse (blah?)
      [forward 2]
      [forward 1]
  ]
end
```